# How to Put Other People's Pull Request in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github

I am fairly new to the eclipse world. When reviewing other people's pull request from Github, is there a way to get their code in my eclipse like creating a new branch. And get their code running on the my server to test out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to go to the Git Repositories view in Eclipse and specify a new repository to clone, using the url of the repository from Github.  Make sure you specify to fetch all of the branches.  After the clone is complete, select "Switch to" on the repository, and select the option to specify the branch to switch to.  Specify the branch you want, then select "Check Out".  You now have the code for that branch.